# If $X_n \sim\text{Bernoulli} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ and $Y_n = n X_n$ show $\left\{ Y_n \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in probability to zero

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification

Let $X_n$ be a random variable that is Bernoulli distributed with parameter $(1/n)$ and let $Y_n =nX_n$, I want to show that $\left\{Y_n \right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges in probability to zero and **does not** do so in mean square.

So what I have done so far is, for the first task (and as I understand it), it is said that for a sequence of random variables $X_n \xrightarrow[]{P} X ~$ if $~\mathbb{P}\left( |X_n -X| \leqslant \epsilon \right) \rightarrow 1 ~$ or if $~\mathbb{P}\left( |X_n -X| > \epsilon \right) \rightarrow 0$, so what I did was:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}[X_n=1] = \left(\frac{1}{n} \right) ~\text{ and }~~ \mathbb{P}[X_n=0] = \left(1-\frac{1}{n} \right)^{1-0}
\end{equation}
Then $Y_n = nX_n$ can be whether $n$ or $0$

\begin{equation}
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(Y_n = n) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = \frac{1}{n}~~\text{ and }~~\mathbb{P}(Y_n = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = 1- \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

But now I'm struggling because it depends on the $n$ if it's even or not.

I would be grateful for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: **Hint:** For $\epsilon > 0$, the event $\{\vert Y_n \vert > \epsilon\} = \{Y_n > \epsilon\} = \{Y_n = n\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$, then for all $n$
$$
\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\} = \{Y_n>\varepsilon\}= \{nX_n>\varepsilon\}.
$$
If $\varepsilon>1$ then
$$
\mathbb P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon) \leqslant \mathbb P(nX_n>1)=0.
$$
If $\varepsilon<1$ then $\{nX_n>\varepsilon\}=\{X_n=1\}$, so
$$
\mathbb P(|Y_n|>\varepsilon)= \mathbb P(X_n=1)=\frac1n.
$$
Taking limits, we see that $Y_n\stackrel p\to 0$.

Also, as
$$
\mathbb E[|Y_n|^2] = \mathbb E[(nX_n)^2] = n^2\cdot\frac1{n^2}=1
$$
for all $n$, it follows that $Y_n\not\stackrel{L^2}\to 0$.

Comment: Just to make sure, why is it true that $\{ n X_n>\varepsilon\} \subset \{X_n=1\}$ ? I mean, if it is supposed that $nX_n \geq X_n$, or am I wrong?

Comment: @ErickGR If $\varepsilon>1$, then $\mathbb P(nX_n>\varepsilon) = 0$. But this doesn't imply $\{nX_n>\varepsilon\}\subset\{X_n=1\}$, so I corrected this error.

Comment: Does this proof work if we have Poisson instead of Bernoulli? Thanks. Also, why did you study only those three cases for $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 1):

Since only the distribution is mentioned, it is perhaps instructive to someone studying probability theory to prove it in the following way. I don't really expect people to value this argument before they have taken a course in probability theory. I'll use some basic facts like:

$(1)$ $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)$ is a probability space (perhaps the most important one) where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue Measure.

$(2)$ If $X_{n}$ converges in distribution to a constant, then it converges in probability to the same. This is very easy to prove and you can take it as an excercise.

Alluding to $(1)$, see that $f_{n}(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$ as a function from $([0,1],\mathcal{B},\lambda)\to\Bbb{R}$ is a measurable function (a random variable) which precisely has the distribution that $$\lambda(\{x:f_{n}(x)=1\})=\lambda(\{x:x\in [0,\frac{1}{n}]\})=\lambda([0,\frac{1}{n}])=\frac{1}{n}$$.

And
$\lambda(\{x:f_{n}(x)=0\})=\lambda(\{x:x\in [0,1]\setminus[0,\frac{1}{n}]\})=\lambda((\frac{1}{n},1])=1-\frac{1}{n}$

So $f_{n}$ is a Bernoulli($\frac{1}{n}$) random variable.

Now $nf_{n}(x)=n\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$.

It is now very easy to see that for any fixed $x\in[0,1]$ we have that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)=0$ for all $n$ after a certain $N_{0}$.

Hence $nf_{n}(x)=0$ for all large $n$. This happens for all $x\in [0,1]$. Hence, $nf_{n}(x)$ converges to $0$ pointwise. This means that $nf_{n}(x)$ converges to $0$ almost surely and hence also in Probability.

It is also very easy to see that $E(nf_{n})=\int_{0}^{1}nf_{n}(x)\,dx=1$. Hence we cannot hope for convergence in mean or convergence in mean squared.

Now, obviously, I have used a specific probability space and this is not what apriori assumed in the question. So, take $X_{n}$ to be any $Bern(\frac{1}{n})$ random variables defined on some probability space. Then $X_{n}$ and $f_{n}$ have the same distribution and also $nX_{n}$ and $nf_{n}$ have the same distribution.

But we have already shown that $nf_{n}\xrightarrow{a.s.}0\implies nf_{n}\xrightarrow{d} 0$. This means that $nX_{n}\xrightarrow{d}0 $ as $nX_{n}$ has the same distribution as $nf_{n}$. And now, since the convergence is to a constant, we directly have convergence in Probability by using $(2)$.